# What ADO.NET book would you suggest?

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net

For now I know SQL and want to write a database program in C#. I tried to read MSDN but it is too difficult for me. I need a book which can explain how ADO.NET works and give some useful examples.
I'm not pro in C# also.

P.S. It would be great if the version of ADO.NET explained in this book is 3.5.

Comment: Dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492350/recommend-a-good-ado-net-book

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Professional ADO.net 2 by Wrox is a good book. You can download it for free from here

http://www.free-ebooks-download.org/free-ebook/dotnet/ADO.NET/