# What is the best ADO.NET 4.0 book for beginners?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, vb.net, ado.net

i am searching a good book to learn ADO.NET 4.0,
book should be  excellent technical overview with practical examples,
I want to learn ADO.NET Where should I start?

Comment: ADO.Net Step by Step from Microsoft was decent.

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1658241/what-ado-net-book-would-you-suggest?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ADO.Net may be a pretty broad topic.  Here are some books that I've had success with:

- [Linq 2 SQL](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1933988169)
- [Entity Framework](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596807260)
- [Classic ADO.Net](http://manning.com/feldman/), this book was originally for v1.1 but it covers all of the basics very well